# "OR" condition in r with NA and blank

Tags: r, conditional-statements, na, missing-data, nonblank

I have recently seen a problem that I don't understand. Here you have:

```
 x <- c(1,2,3,4,45,654,3,NA," ",8,5,64,54)
```

And the `||` condition in `r` is not working at my interest: to identify both NAs and blanks:

```
if(is.na(x) || x==" ") {...}
```

I am expecting the `if` function to return `TRUE` but it's `FALSE` instead. Can anybody please help me understand this issue here? Thanks!

Edit:

Sorry guys I meant to use the argument in a `if` statement so the length should be 1. `|` does not apply here.

Comment: `if` only works with conditions of length 1, as in most programming languages. Notice that `is.na(x)` is much longer than length 1, so... what's the goal here?

Comment: perhaps `ifelse` is what you need

Comment: use it with `any` ,  `if(any(is.na(x) | x==" "))`

Comment: @user95902 For the same input, I am getting as `TRUE`, are you using `|` or `||`. I have used `|`.

Comment: `if(any(is.na(x)) | any(x == ' ')){TRUE}else{FALSE}`

Comment: @not_a_robot `if (condition) {TRUE} else {FALSE}` is a long way of writing `condition`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that both sides of the `||` are vectors

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,45,654,3,NA," ",8,5,64,54)

is.na(x)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

x == " "
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and if either side is a vector then it just uses its first element so

```
is.na(x) || x == " "
## [1] FALSE
```

is the same as:

```
is.na(x)[1] || (x == " ")[1]
## [1] FALSE
```

where both sides of `||` are `FALSE` in the above line.

If you are trying to determine if any element is `NA` or `" "` then

```
anyNA(x) || ( " " %in% x )
## [1] TRUE
```

You could also use `any(x == " ")` for the right hand side but that only works because we know that the right hand side will not be executed if there are any `NA` values due to the left hand side and the fact that `||` never runs the right hand side of `||` if the left hand side is `TRUE` (short circuiting).  If `x` were entirely `NA` then `any(x == " ")` would equal `NA` rather than `TRUE` or `FALSE` which makes the test for `NA` on the left hand side important.

(Note that `|` is different. It does not short circuit. Both sides are evaluated before the `|` is performed.)

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question!